# Automatic Redirection from http to https with .htaccess authentication in virtual hosting

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, ssl, web-hosting

Hi I have configured Virtual host on apache with .htaccess authentication with SSL. Its working fine when I typed url `https://www.example.com:9004/test.php` but when i typed `http://www.example.com:9004/test.php` I am getting this error.

```
Bad Request

Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
Reason: You're speaking plain HTTP to an SSL-enabled server port.
Instead use the HTTPS scheme to access this URL, please.
Hint: https://www.example.com/
```

My *httpd.conf* file look like this

```
 Listen 9004
<VirtualHost *:9004>
    ServerAdmin root@localhost
    DocumentRoot /mnt/work/httpd
    <Directory "/mnt/work/httpd">
    Options FollowSymLinks
     AllowOverride AuthConfig
    </Directory>
  SSLEngine On
  SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /mnt/work/httpd/www.example.com.key
  SSLCertificateFile /mnt/work/httpd/www.example.com.crt
#RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com:9006%{REQUEST_URI}
    ServerName www.example.com
    ErrorLog "/mnt/work/log/error_log"
    CustomLog "/mnt/work/log/access_log" combined
</VirtualHost>
```

My SSL  */etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf* file is

```
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so

#
# When we also provide SSL we have to listen to the
# the HTTPS port in addition.
#
Listen 9006
```

and My *.htaccess* file is

```
AuthType Digest
AuthName "Protected"
AuthDigestProvider file
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
AuthUserFile /mnt/work/httpd/digest_auth
Require user johan
```

What should I do so that when i hit `http:/www.example.com:9004/test.php` it will automatically redirect to `https://www.example.com:9004/test.php`

Please help me...

Comment: I just came across your question, even though it is about 3 months old. Seems similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11621053/redirect-http-to-https-on-default-virtual-host-without-servername). Have you tried that?

Comment: [Link to relevant question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11621053/1935077) posted by [errikos](http://stackoverflow.com/u/1444126) as an answer.