# Redirect http to https using htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, ssl

I have switched from http to https, but now I am getting duplicate content. My .htaccess is:

```
<IfModule mod_security.c>
SecFilterEngine Off
SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I want to redirect homepage and all page/post to https. I have tried all methods, but no luck.

> The page isn't redirecting properly. Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.

No one worked.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.rancahpost.com/$1 [R,L]
```

This:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

This:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

This

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.rancahpost.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

This:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

This:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

How can I redirect all http traffic to https?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Redirect HTTP to HTTPS on default virtual host without ServerName](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11621053/redirect-http-to-https-on-default-virtual-host-without-servername)