# php.ini show server https protocol

Tags: php, https

I want to detect whether the user is navigating via http or https
and switch to https on certain areas of the website. The problem is
that my server doesn't display $_SERVER['HTTPS'] so I guess I will
have to configure php.ini to show it.

I can't seem to figure it out, what values to change on the php
ini to show that.

Thank you.

Edit: I am not trying to find an alternative way to detect https usage.
I am asking how can I edit php.ini so that $_SERVER['HTTPS'] will display
the value when I access https://

Edit2: Maybe it wasn't clear enough. THE $_SERVER['HTTPS'] **DOESN'T EXIST AT ALL**

Update/Answer:
Thanks to @Sheriff I put

```
fastcgi_param   HTTPS               on;
fastcgi_param   HTTP_SCHEME         https;
```

inside this block on my virtual hosts file
    location ~ .php$ {
    }

And now $_SERVER displays

```
[HTTPS] => on
[HTTP_SCHEME] => https
```

Previously It didn't work because I put the fastcgi param values
in the server block. Silly me.

Comment: `$_SERVER['HTTPS']` only shows up when accessing the server through a secure sockets layer(SSL) connection

Comment: Yes and I have accessed it via https still doesn't show it.

Comment: @bornie not all servers populate the `HTTPS` element. it might be better to check if the site is being accessed through port 443. The port being used is pretty much always populated.

Comment: Yes but "$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] can be tricky... for example ispconfig uses port 81 as secure port "

Comment: What webserver are you using?  As @iam-decoder pointed out, not all servers populate that element.  In Apache, this would be
<IfModule mod_env.c>
   SetEnv HTTPS on
</IfModule>

Comment: @bornie, you were clear that the $_SERVER['HTTPS'] variable does not exist in your PHP environment.  What you haven't made clear is what web server you are using.

Comment: As I said I am using nginx/php-fpm

Comment: Sorry.  I see that now in response to @Sherif's answer.  Still, would be helpful to put that info in the original question.  His advice is solid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no php.ini configurations for `$_SERVER['HTTPS']`. This key is set to a *non-empty* value *only* if the request was made over HTTPS. Meaning, `if (!empty(filter_var($_SERVER['HTTPS'], FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN))) { /* request was made over https */ }`.

See [the manual](http://php.net/$_SERVER) for more details...

> 'HTTPS'
>
> Set to a non-empty value if the script was queried through the HTTPS protocol.
>
> > **Note:**
> >
> > Note that when using ISAPI with IIS, the value will be `off` if the request was not made through the HTTPS protocol.

[`filter_var`](http://php.net/filter-var) with `FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN` will return a boolean `false` when this value is `"0"`, `"false"`, `"off"`, `"no"`, `""`, or `NULL`.

## Keep In mind

It's also important remember that PHP only populates `$_SERVER['HTTPS']` from information it obtains through the SAPI (*Server API*) that it uses to communicate with your web server software. So this could be mod_php, or fcgi, etc... Typically this data gets populated from environment variables that PHP copies from your web server through the SAPI. By default Apache httpd *will* include the HTTPS environment variable when the connection is made over HTTPS, however nginx will **not** if you're using `fastcgi_pass`. You need to configure this yourself by modifying your nginx config to set a `fastcgi_param` for `HTTPS`. This will allow nginx to notify php-fpm of the environment variable over fastcgi and it can be populated in your PHP accordingly.

> **Also note, that this can be made even more complicated if you're using nginx as a reverse proxy since the reverse proxy will also have to pass along the information to the proxied node the same way.**

## Important Note

However, you should note that using PHP to redirect to HTTPS by default is probably a bad idea. It's better to configure your webserver to do this instead.

For example, [in Apache httpd you can configure your VHOST to redirect all HTTP traffic to HTTPS by default](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11621187/1878262), which probably going to be safer and easier in case you happen to forget this in some PHP end-point. That is assuming your intentions here are to enforce HTTPS across your entire site or some specific domain.

Comment: Yes I am aware of that. But I don't mind other parts of the website
to be http. I just want the https on login page.

Comment: Your if {} block code doesn't work however in my server. I put an echo "https access"; inside the if block to see if php would detect but no

Comment: What webserver software are you using? e.g. Apache httpd with mod_php, nginx with php-fpm, etc..?

Comment: Hi sherif, nginx php-fpm

Comment: That explains it then. Nginx doesn't pass the variable by default to the PHP-FPM daemon when you use `fastcgi_pass`, In order to make PHP-FPM aware of your HTTPs setup, you need to add a `fastcgi_param` environment variable to the config. For example, in your 443 vhost config you can add something like `fastcgi_param  HTTPS 'on';` to get `$_SERVER['HTTPS']` in PHP.

Comment: Updated the answer for you above

Comment: Thanks sheriff, when I apply that setting I seem to get more items in the $_SERVER array but not the https. Maybe the problem lies somewhere else. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Here's a more detailed tutorial you might find helpful on the topic https://ma.ttias.be/setting-https-server-variables-in-php-fpm-with-nginx/  Also have a look at the nginx docs for more information https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/phpfcgi/

Comment: Thanks, Never mind.  I put the fastcgi params inside the server block
not the location : {} block.

Thank you again for your solution!

Comment: You can also save all your params in a separate file add it to the server block by including it (**just make sure it's the SSL server block only**). That's what a lot of people do anyway. See http://claylo.com/post/7617674014/ssl-php-fpm-and-nginx as another example of that. But here I was just giving a quick and dirty example without expanding on all the additional details :p

Comment: Yes, well now that you made it possible, it doesn't hurt to know the alternative way. Thanks.