# what is key role of redirection HTTP to HTTPS in basic authentication?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, xampp, virtualhost

I am working in ColdFusion 11 with apache web server in windows hosting I have not more knowledge about basic authenticate and so I have little bit confuse about  this

1. why does basic  authentication type store password in
   .htpasswd file so 
             not necessary to store database?
2. how to redirect request  HTTP to https before entering in
   password 
                 prompt?

.htaccess file code which is working fine first authenticate completely then this redirect on HTTP to https but I want to set HTTP to https before entering a password here my httpd.config file virtual host code

```
<VirtualHost  112.192.12.16>
    DocumentRoot C:/Apache24/htdocs/enovis53
    ServerName test.example.com
    ErrorLog logs/enovis-inc.com-error_log
    CustomLog logs/enovis-inc.com-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

my .htaccess file code

```
AuthName "Example CLMS Production (v5.3.0.0)"

AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile "C:\Apache24\htdocs\enovis53\.htpasswd"
require valid-user
```

if anybody knows this then guide me  I don't know this right thing to ask community  all suggestion is acceptable thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. why does basic authentication type store password in .htpasswd file so not necessary to store database?

This is determined by [`AuthBasicProvider`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_auth_basic.html#authbasicprovider)

> Syntax:    AuthBasicProvider provider-name [provider-name] ...
>   Default:    AuthBasicProvider file
>
> The `AuthBasicProvider` directive sets which provider is used to authenticate the users for this location. The default file provider is implemented by the mod_authn_file module.

So in your case, no provider is defined, and the default (file) is applied. If you want another provider, e.g. some db, specify `dbm`, `ldap`, ...

---

> 2. how to redirect request HTTP to https before entering in password prompt?

Usually, some directive is applied unconditionally, unless restricted somehow. To have the password requested only when HTTPS is active, you may try to enclose the `Auth` directives or at least the `Require` inside an [`If`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/mod/core.html#if)

```
<If "%{HTTPS} == 'on'">
    AuthName "Example CLMS Production (v5.3.0.0)"
    AuthType Basic
    AuthUserFile "C:\Apache24\htdocs\enovis53\.htpasswd"
    require valid-user
</If>
```

But now, all content is accessible without password, when requested via `http://test.example.com`. Don't forget to force `https`!

---

Unrelated, but note the security warning from [`AuthUserFile`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_authn_file.html#authuserfile)

> **Security**
>
> Make sure that the AuthUserFile is stored outside the document tree of the web-server. Do not put it in the directory that it protects. Otherwise, clients may be able to download the AuthUserFile.

Comment: thanks, Olaf my knowledge have much clear about basic authentication.but this code does not work <If "%{HTTPS} == on">....If>give other solution so I will Fix it.thank advance

Comment: @vinny I missed the quotes around `'on'`, please try again.

Comment: ok, this is work for me. and ask more question how does get wide knowledge about htacess file and rule?

Comment: @vinny This is like any knowledge, it comes with time. Answering questions here, and reading documentation at `https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/`, of course. It also helps just trying things in a local Apache installation, e.g. WAMP or XAMPP.

Comment: thank you for helping me improve my knowledge and solve my problem , all things working as expected but my internet explorer does not redirect HTTP to HTTPS any idea how does it work?

Comment: Without details, nobody can know, just ask another question. If you have access to the main/virtual host config, this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/27976877/1741542 seems the most elegant. If you must do it through .htaccess take one of the many examples here on Stackoverflow, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5B.htaccess%5D+%5Bhttps%5D+redirect.

Comment: There are also examples at Apache's wiki, e.g. https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RedirectSSL and https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteHTTPToHTTPS